# Fastboot bootloop after formating

Tags: fastboot, boot-loop

device: Xiaomi Redmi 8a (olivelite), unlocked bootloader
i got that problem after this actions:
in twrp i formated
+)Dalvik cache
+)internal storage
+)Data
+)Cache
then i pressed "formate data" in twrp
then i pressed reboot to recovery button(i thought that was needed to apply changes)

---

now i have only acces to fastboot, adb doesnt work
power + volume buttons doesnt work
phone always boots to fastboot
after i got that problem i tried this:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://new.c.mi.com/global/miuidownload/detail/guide/1
this is the solution, i downloaded global miui rom files for fastboot install method, started flash_all.sh script, and it worked